how can I delete or deactivate primary groups in debian gnu/linux?
I want to delete certain groups in my debian gnu/linux system, but some of them are primary groups.
For example, if I want to delete the group news using /sbin/groupdel news
I get the message The primary group of the user "news" could not be removed.

How can I delete it anyway using a shell command?

If I manually delete specific groups in the files:


/etc/group
/etc/gshadow
/etc/passwd
/etc/security/group.conf
Is there anything else I need to consider or delete elsewhere?

Are the groups also deleted/deactivated if I simply comment out the lines in this files?

What is the best way to delete primary groups that are truly not needed?


Edit:
I understand the answers. Still, I want to delete games as an example.
I have now checked with find / -group games 2>/dev/null or find / -user games 2>/dev/null which files use the user or group or have the rights for games.
I found 4 files for dialout find / -group dialout 2>/dev/null, but nothing for games.
I deleted the user and group games, but after a restart, the entry was present again in /etc/group.

Where else should I look for why the entry is being regenerated?
Do I need to search for the corresponding package to delete the number
and the label?
How do I find all entries, packages, and files related to group games?

So, aside from hardcoding, it's not possible.
Did I understand correctly from all the answers?
If I delete a specific package that created the user, the group will be deleted, but otherwise, I have to search the entire system and this will maybe broke my system.
It would still be nice to know where else entries are present for groups.
I have now tried the following (Even if not all of them make sense):
Check group data
getent group games
Search for files of the group
find / -group games 2>/dev/null
Search for files of the user
find / -user games 2>/dev/null
List installed packages
dpkg -l | grep games
Check dependencies of a package
apt-cache rdepends games
Check processes
ps aux | grep games
Search system logs
grep games /var/log/syslog
Check services
systemctl list-units --type=service | grep games
Check configuration files
grep -r games /etc/
Check all files in /
grep -r games /
With the last command, I found a lot, but as the answers already say, it's too much clutter.
Thanks for the answers!

What's the point of this excercise?

@Panki what do you mean?

What @Panki is trying to say is that we can't really think of any good reasons for wanting to delete a system group and manually futzing around in the passwd and group files is a practice that usually ends with "... And then we wound up having to reinstall the entire system because reinstalling from scratch was less work than trying to fix what we'd broken" during IT Horror Story Night at the pub.

You mean that if I delete as an example, the games group on a Linux server, it could have negative consequences later?


You've now asked a completely different question than the original, so none of the answers really match up to it anymore. This isn't helpful to anyone. 2) Only the first two, possibly three, answers on your list of commands are going to have anything even remotely useful.


It could, because the next time you install, whether deliberately or as a dependency, a package which expects the games group to exist, you're entering the dreaded realm of Undefined Behavior. If you're lucky, it'll simply silently ensure the group exists by creating it. If you're extra super lucky it might even create it with the same GID. If you're not, congratulations, your system now contains a potential land mine and neither you nor I nor anyone else can predict when it will go off and what it will impact when it does.

Also, if you still want to delete a system group then clearly you did not in fact understand our answers.

What I understood is that I shouldn't do it, and if I do, problems might arise. I played around to see what would happen and simply restored the backup with the latest state before the changes.

Another viewpoint to this...
You can't delete groups at all.  A group is just a number, and you can't delete a number and make it go away.  It still exists.
What you find in /etc/group is not a group but a label for a group.
So if you delete the label, but the group is still in use, then you have two problems:

The group will be unlabeled and when it is used, it will show up as just a number with a mysterious meaning.
Since the label is deleted, the system won't know that the group number is used, and it may try to reuse the number for a different group label, which could cause security issues with one group being used for two purposes.
In addition to the above two issues, if the group is used by a system service and you delete the label, uses of the deleted group label in the service config files may invalidate the config files and cause the service to fail.

The best way to delete a group (label) that is the primary group for a user is to delete the user.
For service accounts like ''news'', it is inadvisable to delete the user unless you also delete the software that uses that service account.
On a linux flavor that uses a package manager, the user (and associated group) may be automatically deleted if you use the package manager to delete the software.  Unfortunately, users and groups are not managed as tightly as software packages, so there's no trivial way to track what software uses a specific service account.  Fortunately, they are typically named in a way that makes it easy to guess this.  That failing, you may find references to the service account in either ownership of config files or mentions of the group and user in serivce and systemd config files, so if you can't guess, some digging might be required.
You can't exactly deactivate a user.  You can invalidate their password so they can't log in, sort of.  You can change their shell to something invalid so they can't log in via other methods. (This may already be the case for a service account!)  But you don't typically log into a group, so for groups, you can't even do that.   Neither the password file nor the group file support commenting out groups.  So, for instance, if you try commenting out the news group with a # then you now have a group mislabeled as #news.  Since comments are not a documented behavior for these files, even if some tools support it, other tools will not.  As mentioned in other answers, the only way to deactivate a group is to stop using it by removing every mention of it in config files, file ownership, active processes, and possibly hard coded uses in software executables (and probably also some way to use it I forgot).

+1 On Debian-based systems, news also happens to be one of the default system groups with a well known gid. It's not tied to a software in particular but more to a category of software. netnews server/client packages, if installed would expect that group to be there.

Deletion of default groups like this may also cause group id numbers to become unsynchronized which can cause all kinds of confusion later, as hinted at in my answer.

Short answer: You can't delete a primary group.
Slightly longer answer: It's theoretically possible, but anyone who knows enough about Unix to know how to do it also knows enough to not want to do it. This is one of those "If you don't know what it's for, don't remove it" things.
Significantly longer answer: Unix standards specify that every user has a user ID and a group ID. That group ID is the ID of the "primary group" of that user; if you're familiar with databases, it's a foreign key pointing at that group.
As long as at least one user has a given group as their primary group, groupdel won't let you delete that group because doing so would render the passwd and group files inconsistent and the risk of unpredictable behavior (for instance, if you later create a new group with what turns out to be the id of that primary group, the "orphaned" user would suddenly be part of that group whether you intended them to be or not).
If you really want the news group gone, you'll need to delete the news user first, but I do agree with Panki: There are no real reasons aside from a misplaced urge toward tidyness to remove it, and the risk of later accidentally breaking something that assumes the group to exist, while small, is nonzero -- and if something does break that way, you will waste weeks or months of frustration before you realize what went wrong.
Addendum: Do not, under any but the most dire circumstances, attempt #2 unless you want to see what an irrevocably hosed system looks like and enjoy having to reinstall your system from scratch.

Short answer: You can't.
Long answer: You can, but you have to stop using it first.  That doesn't mean just the data in /etc, it means in file ownership throughout all your filesystems.  If it is used in /dev, things may get hairy.  It may also mean in possible future installs, depending on your distribution.  (And some distributions may restore things they stock install as you upgrade.)
As for comments: I wouldn't count on a comment syntax.  (Version 7 documents no comment syntax.)  You might just be changing the name.  (Though I will admit, "#" comments do seem to work for me, even with busybox!)
Edit: Since you tagged "debian", I will tell you that the base-passwd package is the one that restores the stock users and groups, though it does appear to ask.  It appears very little actually depends on this package, so you can probably let it get quite stale (though other packages may need the user/groups).
